# Modify a linked table definition in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

There is a new, recent [bug in MS Access](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/abd458eb-bf5b-4a89-b831-3d90e7e5d266/the-1912-update-to-access-20162019365-breaks-the-way-linked-sql-server-tables-with-identity?forum=accessdev), which causes attached table schemas of linked SQL Server tables to be created incorrectly. You can find the details in the linked bug report, here's a quick illustration (with free-hand arrows):

[image]

Since getting bugs fixed by Microsoft can take some time, I need to develop a workaround. In other words, I need to fix the linked table schema (the schema "cached" in MS Access, obviously, not the real schema on the SQL Server side).

As far as I know, here is no "officially supported" way to do so. This (usually) makes sense, but I need to work around a bug here, so creative solutions involving unofficial ways (modifying system tables, undocumented methods like LoadFromText/SaveAsText, etc.) are more than welcome.

Comment: YIKES. Maybe we should start collecting the methods that **don't work**, so everyone knows what not to bother with.

Comment: `CurrentDb.TableDefs("myTable").Fields("ID").Attributes = dbAutoIncrField + dbFixedField` -- not valid for linked table.

Comment: `Application.SaveAsText acTable, ...` -- object type (acTable) is not allowed for this method.

Comment: Looking into this. AFAIK the only two ways to mess with table definitions outside of the control/restrictions of Access are either directly messing with the database file (hex editing) and messing with a table on the clipboard. Both aren't easy.

Comment: Hmmm... Messing with the clipboard seems like a dead end too, the clipboard format Access uses to copy tables just contains the location of the .accdb + the identifier of the table, not the actual table. There's a bit of data I can't identify, though.