# Why am I having trouble keeping linked table connection from Access to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have an Access 2016 database using SQL Server 2012 as back-end (I have to use this since that's what the client has installed). I'm having a very weird issue. In this database there are two tables which have a primary key field that is also Identity(1,1). I'm able to link the tables to Access without issue (Linked Table Manager is using ODBC Driver 2013 by default). The tables show up as primary key AutoNumber in Access. So far, so good.

However, when I exit Access and go back in, **I find that while the tables are still connected, it is no longer adding AutoNumber for new records**. In other words, when I go into Table Design, the Autonumber has disappeared, Access "forgotten" that I made that an identity field, even though it's still there in SQL Server. Thus I'm obviously getting the "Cannot insert NULL value into..." error, even though it was adding the Autonumber/Identity just fine earlier.

The only solution I've found is to unlink all the tables (not just refresh) and re-do the Linked Table Manager process all over again.  I also tried a custom ODBC string using SQL Server Native Client 2011, but when doing this and importing, the Manager asks me to define a primary key on those tables, as if they don't have a PK in SQL Server, when they obviously do.

Am I maybe using the wrong driver? Should I put this on my SQL2019 instance and just ask them to upgrade? That would be a lot more work since we've already done data migration, so I'd rather "upgrade" from 2012 to 2019 as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59771210/7296893) and [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/abd458eb-bf5b-4a89-b831-3d90e7e5d266/the-1912-update-to-access-20162019365-breaks-the-way-linked-sql-server-tables-with-identity):

Microsoft recently pushed an update that breaks the way Access sees identity fields in tables linked to SQL server. However, even more recently, they fixed this. Make sure to update Access to the latest version, and check if the bug persists.